# How take this indefinite integral

Tags: integration

I'm considering $x \in \left(0,\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$. I'm looking at the integral:

$\int \frac{ dx }{( x^2 - 1 )( 2x^2 - 3 )}$

Using the partial fraction decomposition I get:

$\int \frac{ dx }{( x^2 - 1 )( 2x^2 - 3 )} = \int \frac{ dx }{ x^2 - \frac{3}{2} } \ - \ \int \frac{ dx }{ x^2 - 1 }$

So since $x \in \left(0,\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)$ we can easily write the following:

$\int \frac{ dx }{ x^2 - \frac{3}{2} } = - \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} } \mathrm{tanh}^{-1} \left( \sqrt{ \frac{2}{3} } x \right)$

However, I don't know what to do for the other integral! Isn't it true that:

$\int \frac{ dx }{ x^2 - 1 } = \begin{cases} \ - \mathrm{tanh}^{-1}(x)\ \ \ \mathrm{for\ }x\in(0,1) \\ \ - \mathrm{coth}^{-1}(x) \ \ \ \mathrm{for\ }x \in (1,\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}) \end{cases}$

Is this correct? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe. How is one to remember? But note that $\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$, and when we integrate we get logarithms.

Comment: @andre the problem with that is the logarithm goes through a singularity at x=1 which is within the interval.  Getting to the crux of the matter, the integral is divergent!

Comment: The **definite** integral is divergent. The indefinite integral is well-defined (up to a constant) in any interval where the function is defined.

Comment: Alas, the is not well-defined over the interval given by the OP.